# Trying to do extremely basic (3 categorical variables) Bayesian inference with PYMC3 and NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, bayesian, pymc3, bayesian-networks

I'm trying to understand [this example](https://gist.github.com/tbsexton/1349864212b25cce91dbe5e336d794b4]) of a Bayesian network. Figured I'd dumb it down even more such that it's only looking at three variables: D1, D2, and D3. Each is categorical, with their probability tables given at the top of the code below. I'd like to set D3 = 0 and then compute the posterior probabilities of D1 and D2, like a simpler version of what's done at the bottom of [this page](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/BayesianNetwork.html). I've tried to do this by playing with the code from the first source but have been unsuccessful and I don't understand the error messages.

Any assistance in this would be greatly appreciated - I've really been struggling to implement Bayesian inference. I've tried looking at the [PYMC3 Categorical documentation](https://docs.pymc.io/api/distributions/discrete.html) but it's pretty bare-bones. And the [example of inference I could find](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html) uses continuous variables and seems to be doing a different thing than what I'm trying to do. Or if it isn't, I'm not smart enough to make the connection and use whatever they're demonstrating to meet my needs.

I'm not sure if posting large sections of code is approved here? But I'm not sure how else to do this. Here is my code (a much shorter, simpler version of the code in the first source):

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc3 as pm
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.compile.ops import as_op

d1_prob = np.array([0.3,0.7])  # 2 choices
d2_prob = np.array([0.6,0.3,0.1])  # 3 choices
d3_prob = np.array([[[0.1, 0.9],  # (2x3)x2 choices
                 [0.3, 0.7], 
                 [0.4, 0.6]], 
                [[0.6, 0.4], 
                 [0.8, 0.2],
                 [0.9, 0.1]]])

BN = nx.DiGraph()
BN.add_node('D1', dtype='Discrete', prob=d1_prob)
BN.add_node('D2', dtype='Discrete', prob=d2_prob)
BN.add_node('D3', dtype='Discrete', prob = d3_prob, observe=np.array([0.]))
BN.add_edges_from([('D1', 'D3'), ('D2', 'D3')])

#print(BN.nodes(data=True))
#print(BN.pred['D3'])

def gpm(BN, node, num=0):
    return BN.node[BN.predecessors(node)[num]]['dist_obj']

with pm.Model() as mod2:

BN.node['D1']['dist_obj'] = pm.Categorical('D1', p=BN.node['D1']['prob'])
BN.node['D2']['dist_obj'] = pm.Categorical('D2', p=BN.node['D2']['prob'])
BN.node['D3']['dist_obj'] = pm.Categorical('D3', p=BN.node['D3']['prob'][
    gpm(BN,'D3', num=1),
    gpm(BN,'D3', num=0)
], observed=BN.node['D3']['observe'])

with mod2:
trace = pm.sample(10000)

pm.summary(trace, varnames=['D3'], start=1000)
pm.traceplot(trace[1000:], varnames=['D3'])
```

Comment: The first link to the [github gist](https://gist.github.com/tbsexton/1349864212b25cce91dbe5e336d794b4]) at this time returns a 404 error .

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with PyMC3 , sorry. But maybe you just need the numbers.

Actually I don't understand why you need an inference algorithm at all here.

The  probability tables are fully specified, there is no missing data, and therefore you can just apply Bayes Rule here. Admittedly I don't want to do this with pencil and paper  even for such a simple example. So I've used java-based GUI tool [samiam](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/index.php) here, to use Bayes' rule  for me.

When nothing is observed:
[image]

Interpreting your code `gpm()` and `observe()`, you observe d3 = 1. Then the CPT values  change to this:

[image]

(The state0 values are arbitrary, samiam just assigns default labels stateX). The row-position in the CPT is what matters.